# Xcode won't run after changing folder name

Tags: xcode

After copying project folder to another folder or changing project's folder name, Xcode won't run project. 
I selected  > .
It gets to "Build Succeeded"  then doesn't run.

Xcode 8.0

Comment: Have you tried any of the answers on this site that are related to changing the folder and project names?

Comment: Didn't work.  I then restored folder path and name and still won't run.